# Upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 failed: E:Could not open file /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-rt319ihr/Ubuntu.info - open (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: 21.10, do-release-upgrade, 22.04

I've been using ubuntu and messing about with it for about a year now, and I've always used 21.10. Now I'm trying to upgrade, it's getting angry with me. It says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 477, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 430, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte


Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-rt319ihr/jammy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-rt319ihr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 241, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-rt319ihr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2038, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-rt319ihr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1881, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.updateSourcesList():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-rt319ihr/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 784, in updateSourcesList
    self.sources = SourcesList(matcherPath=self.datadir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 273, in __init__
    self.matcher = SourceEntryMatcher(matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 470, in __init__
    dist = DistInfo(base_dir=matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distinfo.py", line 270, in __init__
    for line in _expand_template(dist_fname, csv_fname):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distinfo.py", line 54, in _expand_template
    with apt_pkg.TagFile(template) as tmpl:
apt_pkg.Error: E:Could not open file /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-rt319ihr/Ubuntu.info - open (2: No such file or directory)
```

I have messed around with a few things on the system like package sources, using pop os's launcher and adding an image onto the ubuntu login screen, but I fail to see how they'd impact this error. I'd love some help, as I understand my version won't be supported terribly longer and I'd like to be able to update. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I have messed around with a few things on the system like package sources"*... it looks like you broke your system. Best to backup any important data, and do a clean install, rather than an upgrade.